# Impossible to write files with root credentials

Tags: shell-script, permissions

I'm trying to launch a small script which fixes a bug in iceweasel icons.

Here is the script. You can find it as a workaround [in the bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=803165)

```
for n in 16 32 48; do inkscape -z -w $n -h $n -e 
/usr/share/iceweasel/browser/chrome/icons/default/default${n}.png 
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/iceweasel.svg; done

for n in 16 32 48 64 128; do inkscape -z -w $n -h $n -e 
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/${n}x${n}/apps/iceweasel.png 
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/iceweasel.svg; done
```

I created a file `tempiceweasel.sh` with the few lines above. I gave it execute permission:

```
# chmod +x tempiceweasel.sh
# ls -la tempiceweasel.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 349 mars   9 16:33 tempiceweasel.sh
```

When I launched the script I have permissions errors:

```
# ./scripts/tempiceweasel.sh
Nothing to do!
./scripts/tempiceweasel.sh: ligne 3: /usr/share/iceweasel/browser/chrome/icons/default/default16.png: Permission non accordée
./scripts/tempiceweasel.sh: ligne 4: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/iceweasel.svg: Permission non accordée
Nothing to do!
./scripts/tempiceweasel.sh: ligne 3: /usr/share/iceweasel/browser/chrome/icons/default/default32.png: Permission non accordée
./scripts/tempiceweasel.sh: ligne 4: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/iceweasel.svg: Permission non accordée
Nothing to do!
./scripts/tempiceweasel.sh: ligne 3: /usr/share/iceweasel/browser/chrome/icons/default/default48.png: Permission non accordée
./scripts/tempiceweasel.sh: ligne 4: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/iceweasel.svg: Permission non accordée
Nothing to do!
./scripts/tempiceweasel.sh: ligne 7: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/iceweasel.png: Permission non accordée
./scripts/tempiceweasel.sh: ligne 8: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/iceweasel.svg: Permission non accordée
Nothing to do!
./scripts/tempiceweasel.sh: ligne 7: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/iceweasel.png: Permission non accordée
./scripts/tempiceweasel.sh: ligne 8: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/iceweasel.svg: Permission non accordée
Nothing to do!
./scripts/tempiceweasel.sh: ligne 7: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/iceweasel.png: Permission non accordée
./scripts/tempiceweasel.sh: ligne 8: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/iceweasel.svg: Permission non accordée
Nothing to do!
./scripts/tempiceweasel.sh: ligne 7: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/iceweasel.png: Permission non accordée
./scripts/tempiceweasel.sh: ligne 8: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/iceweasel.svg: Permission non accordée
Nothing to do!
./scripts/tempiceweasel.sh: ligne 7: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/iceweasel.png: Permission non accordée
./scripts/tempiceweasel.sh: ligne 8: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/iceweasel.svg: Permission non accordée
```

It seems I don't have the right to write files in these directories. I don't understand why; I'm running as root and the permissions of these files are all like the below:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   93 févr. 14 14:25 default16.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  325 févr. 14 14:25 default32.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1845 févr. 14 14:25 default48.png
```

Any ideas why I can't write these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands you copy-pasted were supposed to be single-line commands. Instead, they were broken into three lines each. So each command is the same as if you did:

```
# for n in 16 32 48; do inkscape -z -w $n -h $n -e
# /usr/share/iceweasel/browser/chrome/icons/default/default${n}.png 
# /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/iceweasel.svg; done
```

So basically, in each step of the loop, it's trying to run inkscape, then it is **trying to run the image file as an executable**, then it is trying to do the same for the svg file. The reason you got errors about permissions is, of course, that the images don't have execute permission. The "nothing to do" came from inkscape, which was missing its parameters.

The three lines should be all on the same line. Or the more appropriate way to write this, since you are writing a shell script rather than a single command, would be:

```
for n in 16 32 48
do
    inkscape -z -w $n -h $n -e \
        /usr/share/iceweasel/browser/chrome/icons/default/default${n}.png \
        /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/iceweasel.svg
done
```

Note the backslashes at the end of the lines - they mean the following line is a continuation of the current one. The same applies to the second loop.